# RedHat MultiNest: failed install, issue with CMake/BLAS/LAPACK (or pthreads)

Tags: installation, pthreads, redhat, lapack, blas

I am trying to install [MultiNest](http://ccpforge.cse.rl.ac.uk/gf/project/multinest/) on my desktop running Enterprise Red Hat 6.6 (Santiago).  I downloaded the necessary package (MultiNest_v3.9_CMake.tar.gz), and followed the installation instructions:

```
cd MultiNest/build
cmake ..
```

Although BLAS and LAPACK are installed, I get the following errors:

> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:594 (message):
>     A required library with BLAS API not found.  Please specify library
>     location.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:142 (find_package)
>     src/CMakeLists.txt:31 (FIND_PACKAGE)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "/home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Any suggestions?

The output "CmakeError.log" is below, and seems to indicate that the problem instead involves something called "pthreads".

---

> Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: /home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTryCompileExec4203479411/fast"
>   /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4203479411.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4203479411.dir/build
>   gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
>   Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4203479411.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
>   /usr/local/Ureka/python/bin/gcc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4203479411.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
>   Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec4203479411
>   /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4203479411.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>   /usr/local/Ureka/python/bin/gcc      CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4203479411.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec4203479411 -rdynamic 
>   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4203479411.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function`main':
>   CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   gmake[1]: Leaving directory`/home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec4203479411] Error 1
>   gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec4203479411/fast] Error 2
>
> File /home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
>   /* */
>
> ## include
>
> int main(int argc, char** argv)
>   {
>     (void)argv;
>
> ## ifndef pthread_create
>
> return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
>
> ## else
>
> (void)argc;
>     return 0;
>
> ## endif
>
> }
>
> Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: /home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTryCompileExec3959414027/fast"
>   /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3959414027.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3959414027.dir/build
>   gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
>   Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3959414027.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
>   /usr/local/Ureka/python/bin/gcc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3959414027.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/local/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
>   Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3959414027
>   /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3959414027.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>   /usr/local/Ureka/python/bin/gcc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3959414027.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3959414027 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   gmake[1]: Leaving directory`/home/ianc/Downloads/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3959414027] Error 1
>   gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec3959414027/fast] Error 2

Answer (score 1):

Install these libraries and their devel versions for the build headers

libblas{3,-dev} liblapack{3,-dev} libatlas{3-base,-dev} cmake build-essential gfortran

You can also try installing compat packages.

Answer (score 0):

The error above indicates that the POSIX threading library, `libpthreads`, cannot be found on your system. This error originates from your system-provided `FindLAPACK.cmake` script rather than from something in the `MultiNest` package.

I don't know the specific library which provides this on RedHat, but you should be able to check using `yum provides pthread`. After this you can install it using `yum install M` where `M` is whatever library provides `libpthread` from the previous command.